# Slow code on Nexus 6P

Tags: android, performance, libgdx, android-7.0-nougat, nexus-6p

I'm developing an android app, in which I need to initialize float array. I have this code:

```
private float[] verticesArray;
private int vertexPosition = 0;

public void addVertexAttribute(float attribute) {
    verticesArray[vertexPosition++] = attribute;
}
```

And when I run this code on my test devices - I got strange results: calling `addVertexAttribute` 30 times on Nexus 6P took 75000 nanoseconds, on HTC one x - 15000 nanoseconds, HTC desire C - 70000 nanoseconds. So, why is it 5x times slower on the most powerful device?

My Nexus 6P is on nougat 7.1.1, rooted. HTC One X is 4.1.1, rooted. HTC Desire C - 4.0.1, not-rooted.

Also, I'm using libgdx framework and this is a mesh initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Nexus 6+ devices has data encryption.

[Encrypted vs. Decrypted Benchmarks](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/3qlz69/encrypted_vs_decrypted_benchmarks/)

Comment: Ok, I see. Did some research - in benchmarks it is 2 times slower. Can I circumvent it somehow in my app? I don't want it to be slow on powerful devices.

Comment: @user3470643, No. It is on system level.